# How to assign the correct ROW_NUMBER to the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    --CASE WHEN EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] IS NULL THEN 1000+(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] )) ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] ) END AS C_NO,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId]) AS C_NO,
    EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId],
    C.PreName AS C_TITLE,
    C.FirstName AS C_NAME,
    C.LastName AS C_SURNAME,
    C.Email AS C_EMAIL,
    CASE WHEN EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] = 1 THEN 'MAIN CONTACT' ELSE '' END AS C_COMMENTS,
    CASE WHEN EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] = 1 THEN 'v' ELSE ' ' END AS C_INV,
    CASE WHEN EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] = 1 THEN 'v' ELSE ' ' END AS C_UPDATES,
    CASE WHEN EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] = 1 THEN 'v' ELSE ' ' END AS C_DOWN
FROM
    [CMSTIME].[dbo].[Contacts] C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [CMSTIME].[dbo].[Entities] E ON E.EntityId = C.EntityId 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    [CMSTIME].[dbo].[EntityAttentions] EA ON EA.[PeopleId]= C.[ContactId]
WHERE 
    C.ContactId  IN (SELECT Entity2People.EmployeeId 
                     FROM Entity2People 
                     WHERE Entity2People.EntityId =  307)
ORDER BY 
    C_NO
```

I get this result:

[image]

How can I change my SQL so that I get rows with nulls EntityAttentionTypeId at the bottom and the C_NO still to read 1,2,3,4...etc

I've tried

```
CASE WHEN EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] IS NULL THEN 1000+(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] )) ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId] ) END AS C_NO,
```

but i get something like:

[image]

Thank you all in advance

Comment: You could do something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL(EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId],[very large number here]) )  AS C_NO `  I would think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `ORDER BY -EntityAttentionTypeId DESC` within the `ROW_NUMBER()` function

Since `ASC` will put `NULL` first, then order by non null values, if you order by `DESC` it will put `NULL` last. This of course would reverse the required order of Non Null values, so if you use the `-` operator you get back to the correct order, while still keeping `NULL` at the end.

e.g.

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY -EntityAttentionTypeId DESC)  AS C_NO,
        EntityAttentionTypeId
FROM    (VALUES (NULL), (1), (2), (3)) t (EntityAttentionTypeId)
ORDER BY C_NO;
```

Gives:

```
C_NO    EntityAttentionTypeId
-----------------------------
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       NULL
```

Comment: Yes, that update looks good. Note that you can then simplify the final `ORDER BY` to just `C_NO` again.

Comment: Another good spot. I have changed the ordering as per your suggestion.

Comment: Actually with any of suggested solutions - you don't need `ROW_NUMBER` anymore. This is unnecessary workload. Unless you need new numbers inplace of EntityAttentionTypeId for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think this resulting query should redefine `C_NO` using both `ROW_NUMBER()` and a `CASE`:

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EA.[EntityAttentionTypeId]) +
        (CASE WHEN EA.EntityAttentionTypeId] IS NULL THEN 1000 ELSE 0 END)
       ) AS C_NO,
. . .
ORDER BY C_NO;
```